# IIS7 redirect to another site but show the original URL in browser

Tags: redirect, iis-7

I have a company website hosted on IIS7 (i.e. website.com) and a blog site hosted on Apache (i.e. blogsite.com).  Both sites are located on different physical machines with different domain names.

For SEO purposes, I would like create a virtual directory for the blog content on the website and redirect to the blog site while maintaining the original URL such that:

**http://website.com/blog** redirects to **http://blogsite.com** but the browser's address bar still displays **http://website.com/blog**.  Is this possible in IIS 7?

Comment: I was able to redirect to the blog site while preserving the URL by creating a Reverse Proxy inbound rewrite rule.  Now the task seems to be changing the target site URLs

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given in the comment -- create a Reverse Proxy inbound rewrite rule.  See tip #7 [here](http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/).